# Laravel 5.6 Page Expired (Problem in Linux Cpanel Hosting)

Tags: laravel, authentication, cpanel, csrf

[image: Page Expired(Linux Cpanel Hosting)]

Just Wait. I know the problem. The might be due to

> - no @csrf specified
> - post request but method="get" in form
> - long time (inactivity)
> - No encryption key (optional)

But I should specify something **It works fine in my local env. [ubuntu 16.04]**.

I have same lines of code in live server (**linux shared cpanel**) and that's the place where **page expired** message is seen. Need Help!.

I've already tried running

```
cache:clear
view:clear
config:clear
```

Comment: If you have a list of potential causes, maybe fix each one and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: do `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: do a little experiment. Create a page with content {{ csrf_token() }} and check whether it remains the same across page refreshes or if it changes. If it changes then there's a chance the session does not persist properly.

Comment: @n69s already did `key:generate`. But didn't work

Comment: @apokryfos the `csrf_token()` value changes after each refresh. It's normal to change, don't it?

Comment: No the token should be the same for the same user session. Make sure your session storage is configured properly. If you are using files for session storage make sure the storage/framework/sessions directory is writable

Comment: @apokryfos Actually, the error occurs during the login of user(auth) and  I've full permission of 777 to storage/framework/sessons

Comment: Here's the scenario. You enter the page with the login form. The server sends you the CSRF token inside a hidden field in the form. You submit the form along with the CSRF field value and the server compares what you've sent with what it has stored in the session, however as you said each request generates a new token so the comparison will fail and you will get the "session expired" screen. It's not necessarily to do with permissions but overall it seems your session is not persisted across requests

Comment: @apokryfos Ok. I see. So what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Debugging what's wrong with the session is hard. First step is to check whether the server is sending the cookie correctly and it gets stored on the client. Then confirm that the session the cookie refers to exists in the given session storage driver. You can also try changing the session storage driver to e.g. the database

Comment: @apokryfos Okay. I'll surely do and inform you if anything happens.